# Oracle Managed Provider mixing up parameters

Tags: c#, oracle

I have some code that looks like this (I have simplified it to focus on the issue, but the code is exactly as below with sensitive data names replaced):

```
private const string TargetIdParamName     = "TargetId";
private const string LinkedGroupIdParamName = "LinkedGroupId";

private static readonly string UpdateLinkFromSql =
    $@"UPDATE MyTableName 
         Set LinkFromId = :{LinkedGroupIdParamName}
       WHERE Id = :{TargetIdParamName}";

using (var dbConn = GetConnection())
{
    dbConn.Open();
    using (var trans = dbConn.BeginTransaction())
    {
        try
        {
            var cmd = dbConn.CreateTransactedCommand(trans);
            AddParameters(cmd);

            cmd.CommandText                              = UpdateLinkFromSql;
            cmd.Parameters[TargetIdParamName].Value      = request.TargetGroupId; 
            cmd.Parameters[LinkedGroupIdParamName].Value = request.BreakPreviousLink ? DBNull.Value : (object) request.PreviousGroupId.Value; 
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            trans.Rollback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}

private void AddParameters(OracleCommand cmd)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add(TargetIdParamName, OracleDbType.Long, ParameterDirection.Input);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(LinkedGroupIdParamName, OracleDbType.Long, ParameterDirection.Input);
}

public static class DataAccessExtensions
{
    public static OracleCommand CreateTransactedCommand(this OracleConnection source, OracleTransaction trans)
    {
        var cmd = source.CreateCommand();
        cmd.Transaction = trans;
        return cmd;
    }
}
```

To illustrate the problem, lets say the 'TargetGroupId' was 12345 and the 'PreviousGroupId' was 67890.

From this code, I would expect the record with Id 12345 to have it's LinkFromId updated to 67890.

But what happens is the opposite, record with Id 67890 has it's LinkFromId set to 12345.

Now to get the expected behavior is easy, swap the values assigned to each parameter.

But the question remains, why are the parameters being swapped from what is expected?  And yes I have triple checked that the query is what I think it is, the parameters are passed in correctly (like I did not accidentally name the parameters in the query in the opposite order or anything).  Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you setting `cmd.BindByName = true;`? I don't see it here...

Comment: I was not aware that was a thing.  The examples I saw didn't have this.  Let me try.

Comment: Yep, that's the trick.  If you want to post as the answer I'd be happy to give credit.  Many thanks, I was pulling my hair out on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you tell the command object to bind the parameters by name before executing it.

```cs
cmd.BindByName = true;
```

If you don't do this, it binds them ordinally.  If they were added in the reverse order in which you were referring to them, that would explain the swapping.

I always set that property to `true` because the alternative is not as usable.  It should be the default but that would be a breaking change.  Fortunately, it's specific to the Oracle providers.